# Catch discontinuities in functions

Tags: algorithm, function, math

I have a function which is something like

`f(a, b, s) = arctan(cos(a + b) * csc(a - b) * cot(s))`

I know that it's discontinuous in some places, and that it's possible to "cure" the discontinuities by shifting the function. In this case I know where these discontinuities are, and it's kinda easy to treat them properly. Basically it's just

```
s_discontinuities = [s_0, s_1, s_2]

for i in s_discontinuities:
    jump = round(f(a, b, s_discontinuities(i) + Ds) - f(a, b, s_discontinuities(i) - Ds))
    offset(i) = jump

def new_f(a, b, s):
    exit = 0
    for i in s_discontinuities:
        if s > s_discontinuities(i):
            exit += offset(i)
    return f(a, b, s) + exit
```

and then the same with `a` and `b`. The first question is: are there way to make the algorithm more efficient, and are there any algorithm out there which can work in the case I don't know where the discontinuities are?

**UPDATE** I forgot to specify that I allow for a epsilon (spacing in the y) and a delta (spacing in the x) for any given function (If f(x + delta) > f(x) + epsilon, then is discontinuous), plus the domain is finite.

Comment: First, why the downvote ? Then, it is not possible to compute the discontinuities of a function, for various reasons. First, the definition of continuity involves deltas and epsilons which are as small as one wish. Conventional data types don't allow this. Then, even if you work with "intuitionistic reals", you can assume consistently in intuitionistic logic that all real functions are continuous (ie. you cannot prove that you cannot construct a modulus of continuity). This is a serious obstacle to identifying discontinuities in a generic manner.

Comment: I've updated the main question to reflect you observation. I have no idea about the down vote :)

Comment: For a hint of my previous statement (which is now quite unrelated to the problem at hand), see http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/01/what-does-topology-have-to-do-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Once you have found out where the discontinuities are, you can create an array cumulativeOffset[i] where cumulativeOffset[0] = offset[0], cumulativeOffset[1] = offset[0] + offset[1], and so on. Then, once you have found out where you should be in cumulativeOffset, you just have to do one lookup and addition. You can find out where you should be in cumulativeOffset[] with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search.

Finding the discontinuities for general functions looks at least as hard as finding the zeros of general functions, as zeros of f(x) turn up as discontinuities in 1/f(x).